# Why is my Yellow Dog keyboard layout wrong?

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, macintosh

I just installed Yellow Dog on my PowerBook G4, and it worked, and noticed my mac keyboard. Then, suddenly, the layout went wrong. Most keys don't do anything, and I have letters instead of arrow keys. I logged off to see if it helps, but then I couldn't even log on again (have to type my username). I'm writing this on OSX. Is there any way to get the layout back?

P.S. 
I just rebooted a second time, and everything works - I'd still like to know what happened though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll laugh at me for this one - so stupid!

It turns out I had num lock on, but the light was to weak to see it was on. I must have accidently pressed it at some point. #-o

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find anything specific with YDL (Yellow Dog Linux) and the Powerbook G4. The next time the issue arises if you could run this command and then press the problem keys, this will show you in the terminal what key was being pressed.

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' \
    | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

This will help to establish whether there's a hardware issue or an issue with your YDL setup.

After running the above `xev` command you'll get a little white window that'll pop up. You'll want to put the mouse over this window and then press the problem keys. The name of the key should be showing up in the terminal as you press the various keys.

#### Screenshot

[image: ss of xev dialog]

#### References

- [Powerbook G4 Faulty keys not fixed by replacement keyboard](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=588842)
- [keyboard layout problem on an ibook g4 with ubuntu 10.04](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1560279)

Comment: That looks good, but if it happens again, I can't type any commands either X[

Comment: Yes this is one of the dilemmas of trying to debug this particular problem. If you know it happens with some frequency, perhaps run this command from a cronjob that runs every hour for the first 15-20 minutes and you'll have to wait to be inside one of these windows to try and capture what the keys are showing up as.